# Informatica PowerCenter passing Invalid date to the target table(DB2)

Tags: date, db2, informatica-powercenter, visual-glitch

[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0545N The requested operation is not allowed because a row does not satisfy the check constraint.

Incorrect date - DT_AS_OF (DT_AS_OF:Date:): "06/03/0006 00:00:00.000000000"

My source table(db2) has 20k records  with DT_AS_OF value as 06/06/2023. While loading data from source table(db2) to target table(db2) getting above error due to incorrect date.

After rerunning the job completes normally with correct date values - 06/06/2023.

Any idea why informatica PC behaving like this?

Server - AIX
database - DB2
ETL - informatica PC 10.5

DT_AS_OF (DT_AS_OF:Date:) should load as it is from source to target.

Comment: I think some properties need to be changed in odbc.ini file. Could you pls connect to infa admin ? The property will ensure correct date format is read from DB2

Answer (score 0):

- Different date formats: If the date formats in the `source and target` tables are different, `Informatica PowerCenter` might not be able to convert the date value correctly. For example, if the source table uses the `MM/DD/YYYY` format and the target table uses the `DD/MM/YYYY` format, `Informatica PowerCenter` might convert the date value of *"06/06/2023" to "06/03/2023"*.
- Out of range date value: If the date value is outside of the valid range for the target table, `Informatica PowerCenter` will not be able to insert the value into the table. For example, if the target table only allows dates from 1900 to 2099, Informatica PowerCenter will not be able to insert a date value of "0006-06-03".